# Nylon zipper “tag” or insert pin” part fell off

Tags: clothing

The insertion “pin” (which is the bottom side that slides into the retaining box) fell off my YKK 25” nylon open zipper. Is there a way I can repair/replace this part without replacing the whole zipper?

Comment: I googled it, and it seems to be "arts and crafts" on [Zipper Insertion Pin Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Zipper+Insertion+Pin+Replacement/121750).

Comment: Usually a picture is very useful when describing problems...

Answer (score 2):

Visit your favourite sewing store and ask for a "separating pin set" for a zipper.

You'll need to know the size and the type (e.g. brass teeth or nylon coil).

[image: Package for a "Separating Pin Set"]